# How do I compare a string in an array to a string?

Tags: java

**EDIT: IT'S FIXED, THANKS FOR THE HELP!**

So basically I have an array of strings, a question and an answer

```
public static String[][] triviaData = { 
    {"Question2", "Answer1"},
    {"Question2", "Answer2"},
    {"Question3", "Answer3"},
};
```

And I am trying to make a method that validates an entered input, lets call the entered input `enteredAnswer`. `enteredAnswer` is stored as a `String`.

I am trying to validate that the `enteredAnswer` is the same as the second index of the array.

```
if (enteredAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(triviaData[Config.CurrentQuestion][1])) {
```

This is the code I tried, but I get the error "Cannot invoke `equalsIgnoreCase(String)` on the array type `String[]`"

I am a beginner programmer so if you could help me out it would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

`enteredAnswer` is stored as

```
public String[] enteredAnswer;
```

Comment: Please show the declaration of the enteredAnswer variable.

Comment: Glad we could help; be sure to accept an answer that helped you the most.  It lets the community *clearly* know that you have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`enteredAnswer` is an array it appears. You need a `String` to call `equalsIgnoreCase` on, could you show a little more code?

Also, It'd probably be better to use something like a `HashMap` to store questions + answers. You could do this like so:

```
HashMap<String, String> questionAnswers = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

And later

```
questionAnswers.put("Blah blah?", "blah.");
```

And to check if an answer to a given String question `String question` with answer `String answer` just do:

```
String realAnswer = questionAnswers.get(question);
boolean correct = realAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(answer);
```

Comment: it's not an array, it's stored as public String[] enteredAnswer, the array it's referring to is triviaData

also thanks, I will look into hashmap but for now its only using a few questions.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code invocation isn't working is because `enteredAnswer` is a `String[]`, not a `String`.  Specify which element you want to use to get the `String` you want.